# How to run a template(.yml) belonging to another repository from my current repository in azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

With the below setup, when my pipeline corresponding to my repo runs, it runs the template (template.yml) file belonging to 'anotherRepo'. But when it checks out, it checks out my repo instead of 'anotherRepo'.

Is there any issue in my setup?

Looks like checkout:self does not have any impact and it does not work

My current Repo:

azurepipeline.yml file:

```
variables:
  acceptanceTestsRepoName: 'anotherRepo'

resources:
  repositories:  
  - repository: 'anotherRepo'
    name: ProjectName/anotherRepo
    type: git 
    ref: master

stages:
  - stage: acceptance_tests    
    displayName: 'Run Acceptance Tests in Dev'
    jobs:       
     - template: 'azure-pipelines-templates/template.yml@${{variables.acceptanceTestsRepoName}}'
```

Repo:anotherRepo

template.yml

```
jobs:
  - job: AcceptanceTest
    displayName: Run Acceptance Test in Dev
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
```

Comment: You don't need to checkout a repo to use pipeline templates from that repo, but if you need other files from that repo, you need to check it out with "-checkout: <Name of repo>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` always refers to a repo associated with the build pipeline. In your case, you need to checkout `anotherRepo` manually:

```yaml
# Azure Repos Git repository in the same organization
- checkout: git://anotherRepo
```

This assumes that `anotherRepo` is in the same Azure DevOps organization. If it's not or stored somewhere else (GitHub, Bitbucket, etc...) you also need to add it as a resource to the pipeline defintion. See [Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout) for details.

Comment: "git://" is not needed

Comment: @BoSøborgPetersen TBH, I don't have any first-hand experience with repos hosted in AzD, so thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @BoSøborgPetersen No."git://" is needed in this case. This sample is using [Inline syntax checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#inline-syntax-checkout)

Comment: @Walter Qian-MSFT: Since 'anotherRepo' is declared as a resource, the "git://" is not needed with "-checkout: anotherRepo". Just because beatcracker did not show this resource does not mean that it is not there, as seen in the question by Nethanial.

Answer (score 1):

According to the document about [checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#checkout): self represents the repo where the **initial Azure Pipelines YAML file** was found. [image]
So your pipeline checkout the repo where your azurepipeline.yml file is located.
If you want to checkout your anotherRepo, the checkout step in your template.yml should be `- checkout: anotherRepo`:

```
jobs:
  - job: AcceptanceTest
    displayName: Run Acceptance Test in Dev
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - checkout: anotherRepo
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
```

You can also use [Inline syntax checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#inline-syntax-checkout) to directly check out another repo in azure-pipelines.yml file:

```
stages:
  - stage: acceptance_tests    
    displayName: 'Run Acceptance Tests in Dev'
    jobs:       
    - job: checkout
      steps:
      - checkout: git://ProjectName/anotherRepo
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your response expecially @beatcracker
By replacing the checkout step from self , I was able to run successfully

No change to My Current Repo.
Below change done to another repo

```
jobs:
  - job: AcceptanceTest
    displayName: Run Acceptance Test in Dev
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - checkout: git://ProjectName/anotherRepo
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
```